# How to copy pthread_attr_t?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I guess using `memcpy` to copy `pthread_attr_t` isn't a good idea as the struct seems private on both Darwin and Linux. What the proper way of copying `pthread_attr_t`? There isn't a copy function in pthreads. Doing get/set of all attributes is probably the safest way but it's not future proof.

This is what it looks like on my Ubuntu box, just for reference:

```
#define __SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T 36

typedef union
{
    char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T];
    long int __align;
} pthread_attr_t;
```

Comment: Another reference from `man pthread_attr_t` on Ubuntu: > The `pthread_attr_t` type should be treated as opaque: any access to the
> object other than via pthreads functions is non‐portable and produces undefined results. But I also don't understand the definition of `pthread_attr_t` you post. I ask a question here. Hope someone can explain in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676440/confusion-about-the-pthread-attr-t-definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question, but the answer (judging from the Rationale section of the [`pthread_attr_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_init.html) specification) is that you are not supposed to copy `pthread_attr_t` objects around.  You are right that `memcpy()` etc are not reliable mechanisms (and what's wrong with plain old assignment anyway?).

Comment: And [sys/types.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) states there is no assignment operation defined for a pthread_attr_t

Comment: Thanks for providing some background. Yes, assignment is missing but `pthread_attr_t` can be reused for multiple thread creation though. I think I might be able to get away without having to copy `pthread_attr_t` but I'm still curious whether there's a proper way of doing this.

Comment: When I needed to do this I ended up writing a function to read attribute fields from one pthread_attr_t and writing them to another. Bit of a chore, and a nuisance if someone goes and adds / removes fields in some newer version of pthread lib. But that seems to be what you have to do.

Comment: Would you like to explain why the definition of `pthread_attr_t` looks like that? I ask a question here [Confusion about the pthread_attr_t definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676440/confusion-about-the-pthread-attr-t-definition).