# Confusion about the pthread_attr_t definition

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

When I click *go to definition* in VS code, it leads me to:
`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h`
and the defintion is:

```
union pthread_attr_t
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T];
  long int __align;
};
#ifndef __have_pthread_attr_t
typedef union pthread_attr_t pthread_attr_t;
# define __have_pthread_attr_t 1
#endif
```

What is this union definition? A `char` array or a `long` integer? How can it be used to store pthread attrs? Absolutely nonsense.

---

Then I search *pthread_attr_t* in the *glibc-master* implementation and find 3 most related occurrence:
`glibc-master/sysdeps/htl/bits/pthreadtypes.h`:

```
#include <bits/types/struct___pthread_attr.h>
typedef struct __pthread_attr pthread_attr_t;
```

`glibc-master/sysdeps/htl/bits/types/struct___pthread_attr.h`:

**Obviously this one should be the right one:**

```
struct __pthread_attr
{
  struct sched_param __schedparam;
  void *__stackaddr;
  size_t __stacksize;
  size_t __guardsize;
  enum __pthread_detachstate __detachstate;
  enum __pthread_inheritsched __inheritsched;
  enum __pthread_contentionscope __contentionscope;
  int __schedpolicy;
};
```

`glibc-master/sysdeps/nptl/bits/pthreadtypes.h`:

```
union pthread_attr_t
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T];
  long int __align;
};
#ifndef __have_pthread_attr_t
typedef union pthread_attr_t pthread_attr_t;
# define __have_pthread_attr_t 1
#endif
```

Can someone tell me what's the deal here? Have no idea about that `union` definition. **A `char` array or a `long` integer? How can it be used to store pthread attrs?**

Forgot to say, I debug in CLion and what I see it's the `union pthread_attr_t` structure.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea is to expose those types as sufficiently aligned sufficiently sized opaque buffers.
(
A more modern way to do that would be to use `_Alignas` instead of a `union`:

```
struct {
  _Alignas(long int)
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T];
};
```

)
That allows these types to be declared on-stack (`auto` storage duration) or statically (`static`/`extern`) so as to satisfy the POSIX API, but without exposing the layout.

Technically, such a trick is undefined behavior (violates strict aliasing), but with separate compilation, compilers shouldn't be able to mess it up.

It shouldn't need to be necessary to do any of this as long as there's sufficient agreement that the members of the `pthread_attr_t` type, if any, are not to be accessed directly, but I guess what glibc's trying to do is  deprecate such access even more strongly so that it doesn't get complaints about semantic "breakages" in private APIs that users shouldn't be using in the first place.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand your answer. What I feel confused about is that I think the definition should be the `__pthread_attr` one from `glibc-master/sysdeps/htl/bits/types/struct___pthread_attr.h`, which matches the description of the attributes of a thread, not this `union` one. But what I see in practice is the `union` one, I don't understand how this definiton can be used to set those thread attributes. The `union` attribute is either a `char` array or a `long` integer.

Comment: @Rick The public header says it's a char array so users can't access those fields. The functions that manipulate the type get a pointer and treat it as `struct __pthread_attr*` so they _can_ access those fields. Since the char array is union-ed with `long int`, the struct is sufficiently aligned so this reinterpretation doesn't violate alignment. It only violates strict aliasing so you still shouldn't be replicating the technique, but since these glibc functions are never inlined, this UB shouldn't _practically_ cause any harm.

Comment: So you are saying that it stores the attribute values in a `char` array and then the library reinterpret the array value into seperate thread attrs when needed?

Comment: @Rick Everything stored in memory is a sufficiently aligned char array. You're always allowed to reinpret anything as a char array. Technically, strict aliasing prevents you from going the other way -- reinterpreting a sufficiently aligned char buffer as something else, but this can never cause harm with separate compilation. Glibc is playing what-if, doing just that -- reinterpreting a declared sufficiently aligned char array as something else.